# No output when i run the below javascript and I am new to this, but I want to websites where it uses google maps API

Tags: javascript, html

(Please convert this image of code to code)
[image: Javascript code as I'm not able to attach code]

I am new to Javascript coding and getting error as shown in image

Comment: There's no error in the image and you should provide code so that others could analyze it.

Comment: Posting images of code for a code constitutes poor formatting as it is much harder to reproduce.

Comment: I don't see any error, I just see blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the '&' in the script src got replaced with encoded characters (%26).
Replace those and it will work normally.

Comment: Yes, because when I am using '&' it throwing error when I searched a few websites suggested me to use encoded char